# Can $\mathbb R$ be partitioned into a countable number of dense subsets with same cardinality?

Tags: analysis

> Is it possible to partition $\mathbb R$ into an countable number of disjoint dense subsets with the same cardinality?
>
> Furthermore, is it possible to partition the reals into an uncountable number of disjoint dense subsets with the same cardinality?

This is a follow up question on an old question that was answered here.

[Can $\mathbb{R}$ be partitioned into $n$ dense sets with same cardinality?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/978355/can-mathbbr-be-partitioned-into-n-dense-sets-with-same-cardinality)

There, someone was able to construct a partition of $\mathbb R$ into $n$ dense subsets of the same cardinality.

Comment: For the second question, you can partition the reals into singletons...

Comment: Or, again for the second, given any additive countable subgroup $G$ of $\mathbb R$ which is not all of $\mathbb R$, (say $G=\mathbb Q$,) you can partition it as $r\sim s$ iff $r-s\in G$. The partitions then amount to cosets of $G$. If $|G|<|R|$ then there an an uncountable number of cosets, all of the same cardinality as $|G|$. (Kotel's case is just $G=\{0\}$.)

Comment: I'm sorry, I misstated my question. I of course want the subsets to be dense.

Comment: Then my second example, with $G=\mathbb Q$, works for the second part. Or any dense $G$ with $|G|<|\mathbb R|$.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you very much.

Comment: Alright, I think your answer to the second question answers my first question. Basically, just take a countable subset of the uncountable cosets. Then take the complement of the union of that countable subset in $\mathbb R $.

Comment: @PatrickTam could you explain that more clearly, with symbols please? I don't follow it.

Comment: Let $S$ be Thomas Andrews' set of cosets. We pick a subset $U \subset S$  such that $U$ is of countable cardinality. If we take the union of all cosets of $U$, we get some subset $V$ of $\mathbb R$. Take the complement of $V$ in $\mathbb R$. Call it $V^C$.  $V^C$ has to be dense since it is the union of all the other elements in $S$. Then taking the cosets of $U$ and $V^C$ will give us a partition of $\mathbb R$ into countable disjoint dense subsets.

Comment: ahh, I see the error in my reasoning. $V^C$ is not the same cardinality as the other elements of $U$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first part, find a $\mathbb Q$-basis of the real numbers. This requires the axiom of choice or something similar. Then remove one of the basis element, and you get a subgroup $G$ of $\mathbb R$ with $\mathbb R/G\cong\mathbb Q$. Show that $G$ is dense.

The partition elements are then the cosets of $\mathbb G$ as a subgroup of $\mathbb R$ - that is $x\sim y\iff x-y\in G$.

A similar technique also works for the second question, but a much easier approach there is to take the cosets of $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: $G$ is obviously dense, since it is a non-empty $\mathbb Q$-vector subspace of $\mathbb R$, so it contains $\mathbb Qz$ for some $z\neq 0$, which is dense. @NateEldredge Of *course* $G$ needs to be dense, because the partition is the cosets, the partitions are supposed to be dense, and $G$ is one of the partitions.

Comment: And how does this work for the second question, which wants uncountably many sets?

Comment: Sorry, I mixed up the basis with the subspace it generates.

Comment: Yeah, I was wrong there. @NateEldredge You need to split the basis then into two uncountable sets, and generate $G$ from one of those.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the binary expansion of a number. (Here, I'm using "finitely many" to include zero.)

- Let $A_0$ be the set of those numbers that have finitely many $01$s in the expansion.
- Let $A_1$ be those that have infinitely many $01$s but finitely many $011$s in the expansion.
- Let $A_2$ be those that have infinitely many $01$s and $011$s but finitely many $0111$s.
- etc.
- Let $A_\omega$ be those that have infinitely many $01$s, $011$s, $0111$s, etc.

Does this work?